# Get map location of viewport with angular google maps

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using [this plugin.](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) I am trying to get location lat long of `viewport`. What I am doing is adding event, because I need that info on every change and trying to figure it out how to pull that data of map object.
`JS`:

```
$scope.events = {
  bounds_changed: function(pos) {
    console.log('pos');
    console.log(pos);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map events="events"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

But inside that map object i can't find something that can help me out.

Comment: I think you can use [`getBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) that will return the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. Here is sample [Returns the south-west latitude/longitude and the north-east latitude/longitude of the current viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ref_getbounds). Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds like an solution. I will search how to call this with angular google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was in documentation.
Javascript:

```
$scope.bounds = {}:
$scope.events = {
  bounds_changed: function() {
    console.log($scope.bounds);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map events="events" bounds="bounds"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```